# Using JSX in this.state but it gets rendered as plain text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am dynamically rendering a list of elements. Depending on key-value pairs in those elements, I need to insert other elements in front of them.

I'd like to use `<sup></sup>` tags on those elements, but they are showing as plain text instead of superscript.

How can I use JSX in the state which is an array of strings and not have it come out as plain text?

The line in question is this one: allOptions.splice(index, 0, this.props.levelNames[j]);

The prop would be : `[...., '1<sup>st</sup> Level',...]`

But when rendered it just comes out as plain text.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export class Chosen extends Component {
    render() {
        let allOptions = this.props.chosenSpells.map((val, i) => this.props.selectMaker(val, i, 'chosen'));


        let index;
        let headings=this.props.levelNames;

        for (let j=this.props.highestSpellLevel; j>0;j--) {
            index = this.props.chosenSpells.findIndex(function findLevel (element) {return element.level==j});
            console.log(index);
            console.log(headings[j]);
            if (index>=0){
                allOptions.splice(index, 0, this.props.levelNames[j]);
            }
        }

        return (
            <div>               
                <b><span className="choose">Chosen (click to remove):</span></b><br/>
                <div className="my-custom-select">
                    {allOptions}
                </div>              
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            levelNames: ['Cantrips', '1<sup>st</sup> Level', '2nd Level', '3rd Level']
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display HTML tags in React JSX, you need to pass the HTML string to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` props. Not inside a JSX tag. Please check this official documentation about how to do it: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

So, instead doing this:

```
<div className="my-custom-select">
    {allOptions}
</div>
```

You should doing this way:

```
<div className="my-custom-select" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: allOptions}}/>
```

It is due to security concern. Quoted from React documentation:

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

If you insist to put the HTML string inside JSX tag instead passing to props, alternatively you can use an additional library from this NPM package:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser . So, it will be something looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    ........
    return <div className="my-custom-select">{ ReactHtmlParser(allOptions) }</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. I had to put it in the above code though, not in the div.. allOptions.splice(index, 0, <b dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.levelNames[j]}}/>); did the trick

Comment: I update the answer with another alternative way, if you may prefer to put HTML string inside JSX tag :)